# Let $A: X \to X$ be a Fredholm operator, then $Ax=y$ has a solution iff $Ax=0$ implies $x=0$?

Tags: operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $A: X \to X$ be a Fredholm operator, then $Ax=y$ has a solution iff ($Ax=0$ implies $x=0$)?

I can't see how this is implied by the common definitions of Fredholm operators.

Comment: What made you think the statement true in the first place?

Comment: @user161825 I vaguely recall such a statement that uniqueness implies existence of Fredholm operators.

Comment: As far as i can tell, the statement is that injectivity is equivalent to surjectivity. So this would be true if and only if $A$ has index $0$.

Comment: @user161825 I see. Does my statement work if I replace $A$ with $(1+K)$, where $K$ is a compact operator?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, it definitely works of $K$ is compact and self-adjoint, since this implies index $0$. I would not be surprised if the result carries through to general compact operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are thinking of the [Fredholm alternative](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~ban00101/anman2009/notes-Fredholm.pdf), which ensures that the index of $I+K$ is zero whenever $K$ is compact.